# AJAX wont load URL

Tags: php, ajax

Can someone take a look at this and tell me why the code here wont load the php page I am trying to call?

```
<script src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>     <!-- Linking jQuery -->
<script>                        
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.answer').click(function(e) {
var color = $(this).attr("data-color");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
data: '{ color: "'+color+'" }',
success: function(data){ alert(data); }
error: function (jqXHR) {
...
}
})
})
})
</script>
```

The link that should trigger this is....

```
<div id="red" data-color="red" class="answer">
<a href="#"><img src="images/red.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
</div>



<div id="blue" data-color="blue" class="answer">
<a href="#"><img src="images/blue.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
</div>
```

Test.PHP is just so I can read whats in the POST

```
<?php
     print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is `test.php` in the same level as the page that has the Ajax call?

Comment: I am thinking it has to do with that (e)....

Comment: have you bothered to see if a hit even reaches your server? e.g. monitor the access log while you click away. did you check your JS console in case there's an error in the code somewhere?

Comment: yes the page is on the same level.

Comment: Post your test.php and add the comma here success: function(data){ alert(data); },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to change `data: '{ color: "'+color+'" }',` to `data: { color: color},`

and for sanity purposes change `$(this).attr("data-color");` to `$(this).data("color");`

maybe something like this:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.answer').click(function(e) {
            var color = $(this).data("color");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: { color: color}
            }).done(function ( data ) {
                alert(data);               
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("FAILED!");               
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { color: color },
    success: function(data){ alert(data); },
    error: function (jqXHR,text) {
        alert(text);
    }
});
```